# Can anyone explain this strange behavior with signed floats in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

Here is the example with comments:

```
class Program
{
    // first version of structure
    public struct D1
    {
        public double d;
        public int f;
    }

    // during some changes in code then we got D2 from D1
    // Field f type became double while it was int before
    public struct D2 
    {
        public double d;
        public double f;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Scenario with the first version
        D1 a = new D1();
        D1 b = new D1();
        a.f = b.f = 1;
        a.d = 0.0;
        b.d = -0.0;
        bool r1 = a.Equals(b); // gives true, all is ok

        // The same scenario with the new one
        D2 c = new D2();
        D2 d = new D2();
        c.f = d.f = 1;
        c.d = 0.0;
        d.d = -0.0;
        bool r2 = c.Equals(d); // false! this is not the expected result        
    }
}
```

So, what do you think about this?

Comment: To make things stranger `c.d.Equals(d.d)` evaluates to `true` as does `c.f.Equals(d.f)`

Comment: I tried adding another field to D2 (a `bool`), and the second `Equals` now returns `true`.

Comment: Don't compare floats with exact comparison like .Equals. It's simply a bad idea.

Comment: @Thorsten79: How is that relevant here?

Comment: This is most strange. Using a long instead a double for f introduces the same behavior. And adding another short field corrects it again...

Comment: Weird -- it only seems to happen when both are the same type (float or double). Change one to float (or decimal) and D2 works the same as D1.

Comment: @tvanfosson, long and double doesn't work either.

Comment: Q3 2015, and still able to replicate it :)

Comment: This was just fixed in Core: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13164

Answer (score 396, accepted):

The bug is in the following two lines of `System.ValueType`: (I stepped into the reference source)

```
if (CanCompareBits(this)) 
    return FastEqualsCheck(thisObj, obj);
```

(Both methods are `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]`)

When all of the fields are 8 bytes wide, `CanCompareBits` mistakenly returns true, resulting in a bitwise comparison of two different, but semantically identical, values.

When at least one field is not 8 bytes wide, `CanCompareBits` returns false, and the code proceeds to use reflection to loop over the fields and call `Equals` for each value, which correctly treats `-0.0` as equal to `0.0`.

Here is the source for `CanCompareBits` from SSCLI:

```
FCIMPL1(FC_BOOL_RET, ValueTypeHelper::CanCompareBits, Object* obj)
{
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    _ASSERTE(obj != NULL);
    MethodTable* mt = obj->GetMethodTable();
    FC_RETURN_BOOL(!mt->ContainsPointers() && !mt->IsNotTightlyPacked());
}
FCIMPLEND
```

Comment: Stepping into System.ValueType?  That's pretty hardcore bro.

Comment: You don't explain what the significance of "8 bytes wide" is. Would a struct with all 4-byte fields not have the same result? I'm guessing that having a single 4-byte field and an 8-byte fields just triggers `IsNotTightlyPacked`.

Comment: @Gabe I wrote earlier that `The bug also happens with floats, but only happens if the fields in the struct add up to a multiple of 8 bytes.`

Comment: With .NET being open source software now, here is a link to the Core CLR implementation of [ValueTypeHelper::CanCompareBits](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/7e4afb4fbf900b789f53ccb816c6ddba7807de68/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L2628). Didn't want to update your answer since the implementation is slightly changed from the reference source you posted.

Answer (score 59):

I found the answer at http://blogs.msdn.com/xiangfan/archive/2008/09/01/magic-behind-valuetype-equals.aspx.

The core piece is the source comment on `CanCompareBits`, which `ValueType.Equals` uses to determine whether to use `memcmp`-style comparison:

> The comment of CanCompareBits says
>   "Return true if the valuetype does not
>   contain pointer and is tightly
>   packed". And FastEqualsCheck use
>   "memcmp" to speed up the comparison.

The author goes on to state exactly the problem described by the OP:

> Imagine you have a structure which
>   only contains a float. What will occur
>   if one contains +0.0, and the other
>   contains -0.0? They should be the
>   same, but the underlying binary
>   representation are different. If you
>   nest other structure which override
>   the Equals method, that optimization
>   will also fail.

Comment: I wonder if the behavior of `Equals(Object)` for `double`, `float`, and `Decimal` changed during the early drafts of .net; I would think that it's more important to have the virtual `X.Equals((Object)Y)` only return `true` when `X` and `Y` are indistinguishable, than to have that method match the behavior of other overloads (especially given that, because of implicit type coercion, overloaded `Equals` methods don't even define an equivalence relation!, e.g. `1.0f.Equals(1.0)` yields false, but `1.0.Equals(1.0f)` yields true!) The real problem IMHO is not with the way structures are compared...

Comment: ...but with the way that those value types override `Equals` to mean something other than equivalence.  Suppose, for example, one wants to write a method which takes an immutable object and, if it hasn't been cached yet, performs `ToString` on it and caches the result; if it has been cached, simply return the cached string.  Not an unreasonable thing to do, but it would fail badly with `Decimal` since two values might compare equal but yield different strings.

Answer (score 51):

Vilx's conjecture is correct. What "CanCompareBits" does is checks to see whether the value type in question is "tightly packed" in memory. A tightly packed struct is compared by simply comparing the binary bits that make up the structure; a loosely packed structure is compared by calling Equals on all the members.

This explains SLaks' observation that it repros with structs that are all doubles; such structs are always tightly packed.

Unfortunately as we've seen here, that introduces a semantic difference because bitwise comparison of doubles and Equals comparison of doubles gives different results.

Comment: Then why it isn't a bug? Even though MS recommends to override Equals on value types always.

Comment: For obvious reasons, it also repro's with an `IntPtr` field when running 64-bit.  However, it doesn't repro with an 8-byte-wide struct field.  Why aren't nested structs tightly-packed?

Comment: Beats the heck out of me. I'm not an expert on the internals of the CLR.

Comment: ... You aren't? Surely your knowledge of the C# internals would lead to considerable knowledge on how the CLR works.

Comment: @CaptainCasey: I've spent five years studying the internals of the C# compiler and probably in total a couple of hours studying the internals of the CLR. Remember, I am a *consumer* of the CLR; I understand its public surface area reasonably well, but its internals are a black box to me.

Comment: My mistake, I thought the CLR and the VB/C# compilers were more tightly coupled... so C#/VB -> CIL -> CLR

Answer (score 22):

Half an answer:

Reflector tells us that `ValueType.Equals()` does something like this:

```
if (CanCompareBits(this))
    return FastEqualsCheck(this, obj);
else
    // Use reflection to step through each member and call .Equals() on each one.
```

Unfortunately both `CanCompareBits()` and `FastEquals()` (both static methods) are extern (`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]`) and have no source available.

Back to guessing why one case can be compared by bits, and the other cannot (alignment issues maybe?)

Answer (score 18):

It *does* give true for me, with Mono's gmcs 2.4.2.3.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried it in Mono, and it gives me true too. Looks like MS does some magic inside :)

Comment: interesting, we all ship to Mono?

Answer (score 14):

Simpler test case:

```
Console.WriteLine("Good: " + new Good().Equals(new Good { d = -.0 }));
Console.WriteLine("Bad: " + new Bad().Equals(new Bad { d = -.0 }));

public struct Good {
    public double d;
    public int f;
}

public struct Bad {
    public double d;
}
```

**EDIT**: The bug also happens with floats, but only happens if the fields in the struct add up to a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: Looks like an optimizer rule that goes: if its all doubles than do a bit-compare, else do separate double.Equal calls

Comment: I don't think this is the same test case as what the issue presented here seems to be is that the default value for Bad.f is not 0, whereas the other case seems to be an Int vs. Double issue.

Comment: @Driss: The default value for `double` _is_ `0`.  You're wrong.

Answer (score 11):

It must be related to a bit by bit comparison, since `0.0` should differ from `-0.0` only by the signal bit.

Answer (score 6):

> …what do you think about this?

Always override Equals and GetHashCode on value types. It will be fast and correct.

Comment: Other than a caveat that this is only necessary when equality is relevant, this is exactly what I was thinking.  As fun as it is to look at quirks of the default value type equality behavior like the highest voted answers do, there's a reason why [CA1815](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182276.aspx) exists.

Comment: @JoeAmenta Sorry for a late answer. In my view (just in my view, of course), the equality is always (*) relevant for value types. Default equality implementation is not acceptable in common cases. (*) Except very special cases. Very. Very special. When you exactly known what are you doing and why.

Comment: I think we agree that overriding the equality checks for value types is virtually always possible and meaningful with very few exceptions, and will usually make it strictly more correct.  The point I was trying to convey with the word "relevant" was that there are some value types whose instances will never be compared with other instances for equality, so overriding would result in dead code that needs to be maintained.  Those (and the weird special cases you allude to) would be the only places I would skip it.

Answer (score 4):

Just an update for this 10 years old bug: it [has been fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13164) (**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of this PR) in .NET Core which would be probably released in .NET Core 2.1.0.

The [blog post](http://www.mazong1123.com/fixed-net-framework-10-years-old-bug/) explained the bug and how I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you make D2 like this

```
public struct D2
{
    public double d;
    public double f;
    public string s;
}
```

it's true.

if you make it like this

```
public struct D2
{
    public double d;
    public double f;
    public double u;
}
```

It's still false.

*i*t seems like it's false if the struct only holds doubles.

Answer (score 1):

It must be zero related, since changing the line

> d.d = -0.0

to:

> d.d = 0.0

results in the comparison being true...

Comment: Conversely NaN's could compare equal to each other for a change, when they actually use the same bit pattern.