# Why does the order of both a return and a throws statement cause different warnings about unreachable code

Tags: c#, .net

```
private static ext.clsPassageiro ConversaoPassageiro(ncl.clsPassageiro clsPassageiro)
{
     ext.clsPassageiro _result = new ext.clsPassageiro();
     throw new NotImplementedException();
     return _result;
}
```

shows "unreachable code detected" for the `return _result;`,

```
private static ext.clsPassageiro ConversaoPassageiro(ncl.clsPassageiro clsPassageiro)
{
    ext.clsPassageiro _result = new ext.clsPassageiro();
    return _result;
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

does not show "unreachable code detected" for the `throw new NotImplementedException();`,

Why does the second case not show the warning?

Comment: Exceptions are meant for errors, and not program control flow. I think the compiler knows this, and doesn't see exceptions as a loss of program logic. Compiler warnings are really just a feature of a given compiler.

Comment: @James This must be answer.

Comment: Good question... very interested to know if there is a good answer! (No help from msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0h4st1x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Exceptions show faults. When you reach code past a `return` statement, there's certainly something wrong. If you think about it that way, the fact that this warning doesn't come up is probably intentional.

Comment: interestingly, Resharper marks it as `unreachable` for both methods.

Comment: @Default but there is still no warning in the errors list for the 2nd case (I tested it too)

Comment: This probably explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371564/why-does-throwing-2-exceptions-in-a-row-not-generate-an-unreachable-code-warning?rq=1

Comment: I would vote for the compiler bug.