# Visual studio not marking unreachable throw as unreachable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unreachable-code

Visual Studio 2010 marks, underlines the statement in green, the return in the else clause as unreachable which is logical.

```
public void UnreachableElse()
    {
        if (true) //If true will always evaluate to true.
            return;
        else //unreachable.
            return; 
    }
```

However consider the following.

```
public void UnreachableElse()
    {
        if (true) //If true will always evaluate to true.
            return;
        else //unreachable.
            throw new Exception();     
    }
```

Why isn't any of the throw statement marked, underlined, as unreachable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "marks"? Does it give an error?

Comment: Visual Studio underlines the unreachable code in green and with full Code analysis enabled, it warns for the statement. However it doesn't do that in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371564/why-does-throwing-2-exceptions-in-a-row-not-generate-an-unreachable-code-warning

Comment: Thank you, Nik. 
Thought I had searched extensively enough.