# Why must a return statement precede a throw statement in a catch block?

Tags: c#, computer-science

The code below will complain

```
try
{
    session.Save(obj);
    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
    return false;  // this will be flagged as unreachable code
}
```

whereas this will not:

```
try
{
    session.Save(obj);
    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
    throw e;
}
```

I dont get it...I thought my csc101 told me that return statements should always be the last statement in a function and that it exits the function and return control to the calling code. Why does this defy my professor's logic, and why does only one of these generate a warning?

Comment: "csc101 told me that return statements should always be the last statement in a function": I'm calling this out as outmoded advice from Djikstra that was in reference to more old fashioned languages that have different resource allocation/cleanup models.

Comment: C#...is java different?

Comment: `throw` exits your function in the same way `return` does. Anything after those two statements within the same block will never be executed. In your case, you either need to `throw e` or `return false`. If you wish to do both then you need to alter your function a bit.

Comment: Interesting discussion of "Single entry, single exit" here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: I've found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371564/why-does-throwing-2-exceptions-in-a-row-not-generate-an-unreachable-code-warning) but is about 2 throwing.

Comment: @michael why does visual studio allow the second block and not the first?

Comment: @sirbombay see the end of my answer for that - neither is strictly "disallowed"; I've checked the mono compiler - it reports warnings for both

Comment: heh; btw - I think you mean "defies", not "defiles"

Comment: The reason is simple @sirbombay, it is possible for an exception to be thrown *and caught* before the return statement in the first block. In the second block, there is nothing that is there to catch the exception you are trying to throw - so it is impossible for the return statement to ever execute.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina no, in the first block - the `return` definitely **cannot** be reached.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? If no exception is thrown, `return true` will be executed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`return` will exit the method; `throw` will *also* exit the method, assuming it is not inside the `try`. It can only exit once!

So regardless of the order - the first of the  `throw` / `return` effectively end the method.

As more general feedback, though: if the intent is to return false upon failure, all you need is:

```
try
{
    session.Save(obj);
    return true;
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```

Personally, I would say that this is bad code - it hides the actual problem from the caller, making it very hard to debug. It tells us nothing of *why* it failed. I would say that the better approach is simply to *let the exception bubble*. In that case, there is no point returning `true`, because we would never return `false` - and there is no point catching an exception just to re-throw it. So the entire method becomes:

```
session.Save(obj);
```

(nothing else required whatsoever)

---

If your question is "why does only one of these generate a warning": a fair question, but the compiler isn't *required* to spot *either* of them for you. Perhaps it should spot it. I *suspect* that `gmcs` *would* spot this and warn about it - the compiler in mono is far more willing to point out stupidity.

---

Edit: as expected, [g]mcs outputs:

> Program.cs(15,13): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
>
> Program.cs(28,13): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

for the code below - so it does indeed report both uses as warnings:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() { }
    static void DoSomething() { }
    bool ReturnFirst()
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
            throw; // line 15
        }
    }
    bool ThrowFirst()
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
            return false; // line 28
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ur answer is more detailed and deserves to be the correct answer.pls kindly update to include the scenario where the intention is to let the caller know wether or not save(object) succeed...and still wants to propagate the exception upwards.thanks

Comment: @sirbombay that makes no sense: the way they know whether it succeeded or not is simply by **whether** an exception came up. It cannot **both** return false **and** throw an exception - that simply does not make sense.

Comment: I encountered this standart compiler stupidivity today and really thought once can it be throw statement executed even after return statement? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As tested you can use throw statement with return as " Exception ex2; try{ ... } catch(Exception ex) {ex2 = ex; return; } finally{ throw ex2;}

Comment: As improved solution here : " Exception ex2 = null; try{ ... } catch(Exception ex) {ex2 = ex; return; } finally{ if(ex2!= null){throw ex2;}}" Sorry for spamming.

Comment: @TarıkÖzgünGüner i tried your solution but it is not working

Answer (score 13):

You are wrong: **both** your examples raise the *Dead code* compiler error because both `throw` and `return` mark the exit point of a method and no further code is allowed beyond that point.

However, whether the compiler allows it or not, the code below either the `throw` or the `return` is still dead and will never get a chance to execute.

(NOTE: this question was initially tagged as Java and my first sentence pertains to Java compiler semantics)

Comment: @musefan: I mean pointing that question itself is wrong as both code gives compilation error.

Comment: No in VS2012, the `return -> throw` give no warnig while the `throw -> return` yes.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: Just confirm that is correct (C# in VS 2012)

Comment: i'm using vs2008 and it allows the second code block while flagging the first

Comment: @musefan for info, the mono compiler (mcs / gmcs) reports both of them

Answer (score 1):

Because any code after the return statement within a code block will be unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on C# and may or may not be applicable to Java.

In this case, you do not actually need the `return` statement. `throw` will be the last step of the function.

In this example, both `return` and `throw` will end the current function. Regardless of which way around you put them, then first will always prevent the second from being reachable.

**NOTE**: The exception to when a `throw` statement would end the function is if it was to be wrapped in a `try` block. In this case, the `throw` function would end execution of the remaining `try` block code, and move to the most relevant `catch` block - or `finally` block if a `catch` is not applicable.

Your code should look like this:

```
try
{
    session.Save(obj);

    return true;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

However, there is not much point in having the try/catch anyway if all you are doing is re-throwing the exception.

---

To specifically answer your only question:

> Why does this defiles my professor's logic?

Well either your professor is wrong, or you have misunderstood them

Answer (score 0):

The "return false;" in the catch block is unreachable because of the "throw e;" just before it. When the code executes in the catch block the first line is a throw which means you immediately throw the exception to the calling method and therefore any following code does not get executed.

```
try
    {
        session.Save(obj);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e; //Throws exception to calling method
        return false;  //this will be flagged as unreachable code

    }
```

I hope this helps.