# Why is "return; throw .." not considered unreachable code?

Tags: c#, exception, return

I have a method in a C# program that essentially looks like this:

```
public bool Connect()
{
    try
    {
        // try to connect
        return true;
    }
    catch(MySqlException e)
    {
        throw new CustomException(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue is about the  order of these specific lines. The compiler complains about this and indicates the `return` statement as unreachable code:

```
throw new CustomException(e.Message);
return false;
```

But it does not complain about this:

```
return false;
throw new CustomException(e.Message);
```

Why does the first one not work, but the second one does? Doesn't a  method exit as soon as it hits a `return` statement?

Comment: They both "work". And in both cases, the second line is unreachable. So it  seems what you really want to know is, why does the throw after the return not generate a compile warning too?

Comment: C# uses an imperfect heuristic to detect unreachable code, because you cannot deterministically detect all unreachable code (that would require solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is impossible). They simply haven’t built in a rule to detect your second statement, even though it’s definitely unreachable.

Comment: To any future people wanting to (attempt to) answer this question. 1. Please read the *whole* question before attempting to answer. 2. The question is really this: Why does code that first throws then returns produce a compiler warning, whereas if you first return, then throw, doesn't?

Comment: The same compiler warning is reproduce (and not reproduced, respectively) when removing the `try/catch`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Which seems silly as `return` is 'definitely terminating'; Java has the algorithm rules well defined, and I believe C# does although I am much less familiar with its spec.

Comment: I agree that this question is exactly that, a duplicate of the linked question, however the "answer" there does not in any way answer the question. It basically says "that's just how it is".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, still seems like it should be closed as a dup, but if you think I should undo my vote, I'll oblige.

Comment: An even better explanation is here (from Eric Lippert himself): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371564/why-does-throwing-2-exceptions-in-a-row-not-generate-an-unreachable-code-warning

Comment: I reopened it. A question specifically asking *why* is in no way a duplicate of a question saying "that's just how it is". Just as you, if someone else votes to close it as a duplicate, I'll leave it alone, but in my opinion the linked question does in no way answer it. To be honest, I fail to see how the answer on that question answers that question too. A question about "why" is never answered with "because".

Comment: And yes, I agree, @KirkWoll probably has the best duplicate so I'll mark this as a duplicate of that instead.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, think you meant hatchet, but I agree with everything you said. :)

Comment: Uhm, yes, whiskey, evening, tired, you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, it looks like its been in the bug database for years and they still haven't fixed it. Probably very low on the priority list.

Comment: I wonder what ReSharper thinks of that code... And what about code analysis.

Comment: OK, ReSharper correctly "flags" both unreachable lines as unreachable by coloring them grey. Code analysis is oblivious to this problem. Pop quiz, did you know you can integrate ReSharper code analysis into your build process using the [ReSharper command line tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html) ?