# Why does this simple struct return different hash codes for objects that are equal?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Quick example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

var d1 = new DateTime(2023, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var d2 = new DateTime(2023, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

var foo1 = new Foo { d = d1 };
var foo2 = new Foo { d = d2 };

Console.WriteLine($"d1.Equals(d2): {d1.Equals(d2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"d1.GetHashCode() == d2.GetHashCode(): {d1.GetHashCode() == d2.GetHashCode()}");
Console.WriteLine($"foo1.Equals(foo2): {foo1.Equals(foo2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"foo1.GetHashCode() == foo2.GetHashCode(): {foo1.GetHashCode() == foo2.GetHashCode()}");

struct Foo {
    public DateTime d;
}
```

Prints:

```
d1.Equals(d2): True
d1.GetHashCode() == d2.GetHashCode(): True
foo1.Equals(foo2): True
foo1.GetHashCode() == foo2.GetHashCode(): False
```

([playground, net7](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yQ3fkD))

`DateTime` intentionally ignores `Kind` in its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. However, it seems that it is not ignored in the `GetHashCode` methods of a simple struct which contains a `DateTime`.

My guess is it might be related to this optimization which uses `memcmp` when all fields are 8 bytes wide (discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508945/can-anyone-explain-this-strange-behavior-with-signed-floats-in-c)).

However, is it possible that it is used only for `GetHashCode` and not for `Equals`? Is it "only" an issue with `DateTime` or is it more general, e.g. this optimization doesn't check for overriden `Equals`/`GetHashCode`?

Comment: My *guess* is that `ValueType` *does* normally check for overridden Equals/GetHashCode, but has an (incorrect) exception for DateTime that leads it to believe it can use just the bit pattern. Would need to test with another custom struct... Fundamentally though, it's basically always a good idea to override Equals/GetHashCode in structs anyway (and implement `IEquatable<T>`).

Comment: I reported this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82825